# attempt to index nil with 'CFrame'

Tags: lua, roblox

i was trying to make random spawns but sometimes, it gives me an error attempt to index nil with 'CFrame' when i enter the portal.

Here is the code

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    
    
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild('Humanoid') and not db and not hit.Parent.Parent:IsA("Tool") then
        db = true
        local spawns = workspace.Spawns
        local spawnPoint = math.random(1,13)
        local plr = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
        local ss = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
        plr.InLobby.Value = false
        if UIS.TouchEnabled == true then
            script.Ability:Clone().Parent = plr.PlayerGui
            end
        if not plr.Backpack:FindFirstChild(plr.leaderstats.Glove.Value) and plr.leaderstats.Glove.Value ~= "edgelord" or plr.leaderstats.Glove.Value ~= "ḇ̵̰̪̙̭̎̓o̴̰͈͊̈̓̓̕b̶̨̀͐͌͑͒" then
            if ss:FindFirstChild(plr.leaderstats.Glove.Value) then
            
            ss:FindFirstChild(plr.leaderstats.Glove.Value):Clone().Parent = plr.Backpack
            hit.Parent.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = spawns:FindFirstChild(spawnPoint).CFrame
            wait(2)
                db = false
            
                end
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "attempt to index nil" error is always telling you that the object you're trying to get a value out of doesn't exist.

In this case, it's probably `spawns:FindFirstChild(spawnPoint)` that doesn't exist. The `FindFirstChild` searches the names of the children, and you are passing in a number between 1 - 13. This makes an assumption about the names of the children that is unnecessary and is likely the source of your error.

A safer way to access these objects is to simply get all of the spawn points as an array, and then access a random index within that array.

```lua
local spawns = workspace.Spawns:GetChildren()
local randomIndex = math.random(1, #spawns)
local targetCFrame = spawns[randomIndex].CFrame
hit.Parent.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = targetCFrame
```